# How do I change this API Endpoint to check for overlapping meetings?

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, endpoint

I am currently working on an API endpoint for my application that needs to find the earliest common available time slot for a group of selected people. The API endpoint receives a list of person IDs and a specific date as query parameters. It then reads the availability data from a CSV file and filters the slots based on the selected person IDs.

The problem I am facing is that the current implementation is not correctly identifying the earliest common available time slot after considering the occupied slots. The API endpoint is displaying incorrect results where slots that are already occupied are considered as available.

Here's an example of the issue I am encountering:

```
{
  "isAvailable": false,
  "occupiedSlots": [
    { "slot": "6:45 - 7:00", "personId": "9", "start": "6:45", "end": "7:00" },
    { "slot": "7:15 - 7:30", "personId": "9", "start": "7:15", "end": "7:30" },
    { "slot": "8:00 - 8:30", "personId": "9", "start": "8:00", "end": "8:30" },
    { "slot": "9:00 - 13:00", "personId": "9", "start": "9:00", "end": "13:00" },
    { "slot": "9:00 - 11:00", "personId": "39", "start": "9:00", "end": "11:00" }
  ],
  "earliestAvailableTimes": ["11:00"]
}
```

In the example above, the API is returning "11:00" as the earliest available time slot for the selected people.

The correct earliest available time slot should be "13:00", as it is the earliest time slot after considering the occupied slots for all selected people.

I suspect the issue lies in the logic of checking the 1-hour gap between slots and considering already occupied slots as available. However, I have tried adjusting the code without success.

Could someone please help me identify the problem with the current implementation and suggest the correct logic to find the earliest common available time slot for all selected people?

It's my API Endpoint:

```
app.get('/checkAvailability', (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { ids, date } = req.query;
    const selectedIds = ids.split(',');

    const results = [];

    fs.createReadStream('4busy.csv')
    .pipe(csv())
    .on('data', (data) => {
      results.push(data);
    })
    .on('end', () => {
      const occupiedSlots = results
        .filter((availability) => selectedIds.includes(availability.personId))
        .map((availability) => {
          const interval = availability.interval.toUpperCase();
          const startDate = new Date(availability.date);
          const currentDate = new Date(date);

          if (interval === 'D') {
            return {
              slot: `${availability.start} - ${availability.end}`,
              personId: availability.personId,
              end: availability.end
            };
          } else if (interval === 'W') {
            const daysDiff = Math.floor((currentDate - startDate) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
            if (daysDiff % 7 === 0 && startDate <= currentDate) {
              return {
                slot: `${availability.start} - ${availability.end}`,
                personId: availability.personId,
                end: availability.end
              };
            }
          } else if (interval === 'M') {
            const weeksDiff = weekCount(currentDate) - weekCount(startDate);
            if (weeksDiff % 4 === 0 && startDate <= currentDate) {
              return {
                slot: `${availability.start} - ${availability.end}`,
                personId: availability.personId,
                end: availability.end
              };
            }
          }
        })
        .filter((slot) => slot !== undefined);

        // Sort occupied slots by 'start' time in ascending order
        occupiedSlots.sort((a, b) => {
          const aTime = parseInt(a.slot.split(' - ')[0].split(':')[0]) * 60 + parseInt(a.slot.split(' - ')[0].split(':')[1]);
          const bTime = parseInt(b.slot.split(' - ')[0].split(':')[0]) * 60 + parseInt(b.slot.split(' - ')[0].split(':')[1]);
          return aTime - bTime;
        });

        // Find all possible earliest available times after considering occupied slots
        const earliestAvailableTimes = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < occupiedSlots.length - 1; i++) {
          const currentSlotEndTime = occupiedSlots[i].end;
          const nextSlotStartTime = occupiedSlots[i + 1].slot.split(' - ')[0];
          const aTime = parseInt(currentSlotEndTime.split(':')[0]) * 60 + parseInt(currentSlotEndTime.split(':')[1]);
          const bTime = parseInt(nextSlotStartTime.split(':')[0]) * 60 + parseInt(nextSlotStartTime.split(':')[1]);

          // Check if there is at least a 1-hour gap between the current slot's end time and the next slot's start time
          if (bTime - aTime >= 60) {
            earliestAvailableTimes.push(currentSlotEndTime);
          }
        }

        // Check if occupiedSlots array is not empty
        if (occupiedSlots.length > 0) {
          // Check the gap between the last occupied slot's 'end' time and the end of the day (18:00)
          const lastSlotEndTime = occupiedSlots[occupiedSlots.length - 1].end;
          const endOfDayTime = 20 * 60; // Convert 18:00 to minutes
          const lastSlotEndTimeMinutes = parseInt(lastSlotEndTime.split(':')[0]) * 60 + parseInt(lastSlotEndTime.split(':')[1]);
          if (endOfDayTime - lastSlotEndTimeMinutes >= 60) {
            earliestAvailableTimes.push(lastSlotEndTime);
          }
        } else {
          // Handle the case when occupiedSlots is empty (e.g., reload the page or show an error message)
          // For example:
          console.log("No occupied slots found. Please try again later.");
          // You can also reload the page using JavaScript:
          window.location.reload();
        }
      
        if (earliestAvailableTimes.length > 0) {
          res.json({ isAvailable: false, occupiedSlots, earliestAvailableTimes });
        } else {
          res.json({ isAvailable: true });
        }
      });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  }
});
```

4busy.csv:

> personId,group,date,start,end,interval,slot
> 9,Zarząd,2023-07-17,7:15,7:30,D,1
> 9,Zarząd,2023-07-18,8:00,8:30,W,2
> 9,Zarząd,2023-07-21,7:45,8:45,W,3
> 9,Zarząd,2023-07-21,8:45,9:30,W,4
> 9,Zarząd,2023-07-18,9:00,13:00,W,5
> 9,Zarząd,2023-07-20,9:00,10:00,W,7
> 9,Zarząd,2023-07-20,8:00,8:15,W,8
> 9,Zarząd,2023-07-20,7:30,7:45,W,9
> 9,Zarząd,2023-07-17,6:45,7:00,D,10
> 39,Zarząd,2023-07-21,10:00,12:00,W,1
> 39,Zarząd,2023-07-19,9:00,10:00,W,2
> 39,Zarząd,2023-07-18,9:00,11:00,W,3
> 39,Zarząd,2023-07-20,9:00,10:00,W,5

Comment: Is that possible to have two slot in the same time ?  i see one from 9 to 11 and one from 9 to 13, it is a bit confusing

Comment: but that's two different people: id 9 and id 39

Comment: i got it so how many people can take an appointment at the same time ? Two or more ? You have to consider this notion.

Comment: I mean, many people can have meetings at the same time. The case is to get closest meeting time even if they're overlapping

Example:

Person1: 9:00-13:00
Person2: 10:00-11:00

My endpoint shows that closest meeting time is 11:00 while it should be 13:00 cause Person 2 can't meet at 11:00

Comment: you should consider using timestamp for a simplier approach